# Android Wear Google Play Store Listing error

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I have published an app called My VIT on Android. This app is compatible with Android Wear and I have also uploaded Android Wear graphic assets on Store Listings on Developer Console. 
Still the watch icon for "Enhanced for Android Wear" tag isn't shown on Play Store. Please suggest me way to solve this.

Comment: Have you ticked the box for *Distribute your app on Android Wear* on the Pricing & Distribution page? Have you contacted Play Store support through the "Help" icon at the upper right of the dev console?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Did that now. Thanks.